# JavaScript Browser Interference

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, error-handling

I have an application that 99% of the time functions correctly. It's a relatively simple checkout system - the user submits a form, it runs through validation (all fields contain something), then fires against a payment processor. The payment processor uses an API to process the order and returns `error` or `success` responses, `error` returning a message, `success` passing the user to a 'Thank You' page with the order information.

The problem we're having is we're hearing about customers who say that when it starts processing a message appears (it's supposed to) in an overlay, then just hangs there. I've coded in a timeout which is supposed to wait 25 seconds, then send the user to the `success` page (minus any success information) which then tells them there was an error. However, in a small number of instances this is not happening.

I've tested this on the gauntlet of browsers and cannot replicate it, so I'm wondering...

1. If it's possible that a toolbar or plugin on the browser could be preventing the scripts from running correctly.
2. If there's some way I can programatically check for errors like this and push the user on regardless.

Here's the code for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/XaP7z/

I know this is a long-winded and somewhat vague question but I'm grasping at straws and the client is not happy (regardless of this being a <1% issue).

Comment: Well you're not doing anything to handle possible failures from the `$.post()` call, are you?

Comment: Can you tell us what browser the users with problems are using? If they're all using old versions of IE, for instance, you could narrow down the problem to a certain number of features that browser doesn't support.

Comment: A toolbar or plugin could definitely be interfering with it, though i also wouldn't rule out people having cookies disabled and/or using some really old browser, or having odd security settings.

Comment: @Pointy That's why I never use `$.post` & `$.get` - it's just easier to just make an `$.ajax` call and specify everything you need

Comment: Like I said - we've tested every browser we can (browserstack and local VMs).

Comment: You'd be better off spending your time trying to explain the 80:20 rule to the client.

Comment: @JamesGaunt - Yeah, that was were I spent a large portion of my time, but their not exactly cool with even 99:1

Comment: @Fluidbyte - I feel you pain. But you can't account for everything. Visitors could be losing internet connection, their browser could be hanging due to a local software issue, they could just be terminally stupid. I suppose it depends on the overall volumes you're handling - but in any large scale site errors (real or visitor imagined/caused) will _always_ occur. Refund them 1% of their fee and tell them to get over it.

Comment: If there's an HTTP problem with the request, the `$.post()` callback won't be invoked, I don't think. That's what I meant by "handling possible failures".

Comment: @JamesGaunt you're right but I think a good application is responsible for doing all it can to handle network errors. The code involved here isn't doing *anything* for that.

Comment: @Pointy - doesn't the timeout cover this? I have to admit I haven't studied the code in depth - I'm coming at this from a philosophical perspective.

Comment: @Pointy a failure to the post is either handled (server side) with a return `error` and client side with the timeout. If there's another approach I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Oh I see; well yes that *looks* OK.  Well it could be that something's causing JavaScript errors on the page for some reason, and those are causing your code to fail.

Comment: @Pointy - that's my thought, and the only variable seems to be the browser (and any crap loaded on it that could be running JS).